# Critical worker-timeout when the application is hosted (Python, flask, api, render)

Tags: python, flask, timeout, openai-api

I'm creating a web-app using python and flask. The app makes several calls to openai API for generating text and also it makes a call to stability AI for image generation. The application is hosted on render (free plan). The problem is that the application returns me a [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT when executed on a remote server (if I use it locally everything is fine). I've tried to set the gunicorn timeout to an higher time (I set it to 5 minutes) but it seems not to work as well. I've also thought that it could be related to a lack of resources, but from the render support they said that in this case the server would have been restarted.
Can anyone help me?
If you need the code for extra-information let me know.